# Capability field's value is not visible while adding the product to the opportunity

Tags: opportunity, opportunity-lineitem

I have custom field with the name "capability" in products. when am adding the products to the opportunity, i was not able to get the capability's value.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have FLS for those fields configured for respective profile you are testing and make sure field can be editable and not Read only.

For adding the fields on the "Add Product" screen here are the screeshots

1.Edit the Opportunity Product Layout

[image]

2.Edit Multi-Line Layout

[image]

Comment: Field is visible but not the value

Comment: Thanks @Mohith I missed to check wf field update on adding the products.

Comment: In my case, i am using wf field update to populate the field in multi-line layout. Now i can able to see only field not the value. is it possble to show the value as well.